# regex - optional word after using non-greedy

Tags: php, regex

i have some urls like :

```
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/arabic
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/danish
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/farsi_persian
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3?wdwrf
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3?wdwrf=ok&nep=1
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/arabic/
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/danish/
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/farsi_persian/
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/farsi_persian/?sdsf
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/farsi_persian/?sdsf&dfe=pl

http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/arabic/1627077
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/danish/1629022
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/farsi_persian/1593665
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/arabic/1627077/
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/danish/1629022//
http://exmple.com/subtitles/my-subtitle-name-3/farsi_persian/1593665/?1xds
```

i am trying to get subtitle name , in this case its `my-subtitle-name-3` so it should capture `my-subtitle-name-3` in all of above urls

it tried this regex `\/subtitles\/(.*?)\/.*` so it does not match for URLs that have not any additional `/` at URL,

I tired make `/` optional at my regex so I used `\/subtitles\/(.*?)\/?.*` too, but it's not worked at all

here are test links :

https://regex101.com/r/BOIfzG/1

https://regex101.com/r/BOIfzG/2 ==> i tried make `\` optional after using non-greedy but it's not worked

The first one detects most URLs and the second one not working

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to your issue.

`/subtitles/([^/?\s]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/VSzC0u/2

Thanks to @preaction